# Cannot access Django webpage when using Docker to run a virtualized Django project on Linux server

Tags: linux, django, nginx, docker, server

I set up a docker for a Django project on a Linux server. However, when I run the Django project, it cannot be accessed through the Internet. The project is set up using Docker automatic build and pulled using docker-compose. The docker-compose ps command gives the following output, indicating the project is running.

```
~/otree-docker$ docker-compose ps
         Name                       Command               State         Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
otreedocker_database_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      5432/tcp
otreedocker_otree_1      /bin/sh -c /opt/otree/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
otreedocker_redis_1      docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp
```

When I use nginx to set up a test webpage, however, it can be accessed without any issue.

Most importantly, I used the same Docker automatic build on another server, it ran without any issue, so the issue must be the setup of the server, not the Django project or the Docker automatic build. Anyone can suggest where to identify the issue? I have been struggling with this issue for several days, and have no idea where to check.

BTW, when I check the usage of the ports when running the Django project, I get the following:

```
~$ netstat -ntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49471           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4410            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::4000                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::10050                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9390                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5555                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::46361                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::4410                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

When I put up a test webpage using nginx, I get the following:

```
~$ netstat -ntl
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49471           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4410            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::4000                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::10050                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9390                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5555                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::46361                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::4410                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Django uses tcp6 while nginx uses tcp. I don't know too much about the server setup, but might this issue be caused by some restriction on the tcp6 protocol on the server?

My docker-compose.yml is as follows

```
ersion: "2"

services:

  database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    restart: always
    read_only: true
    volumes:
      - "database:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    tmpfs:
      - "/tmp"
      - "/run"
    networks:
      db-net:

  otree:
    # if using Docker Hub, leave "build: ./" commented out.
    # if you want to build an image locally, uncomment it.

    # build: ./
    image: myusername/otree_experiment:latest
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@database/${POSTGRES_DATABASE}"
      OTREE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${OTREE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      OTREE_PRODUCTION: ${OTREE_PRODUCTION}
      OTREE_AUTH_LEVEL: ${OTREE_AUTH_LEVEL}
    ports:
      - ${OTREE_PORT}:80
    volumes:
    volumes:
      - "otree-resetdb:/opt/init"
    # Uncomment for live editing
    #  - ./:/opt/otree
    restart: always
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    networks:
      - db-net
      - redis-net

  redis:
    image: redis
    command: "redis-server"
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    restart: always
    read_only: true
    networks:
      - redis-net

volumes:
  database:
  otree-resetdb:

networks:
  db-net:
  redis-net:
```

Comment: How are you running django? Gunicorn, uwsgi or what?

Comment: Sorry... as a newbie, I am not familiar with uwsgi, etc... I use a Ubuntu server if that's what you are asking...

Comment: No problem. Do this in order to see whether the port is correctly opened inside the container: `docker-compose exec otree ss -ltnp | cat`

Comment: rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"ss\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: Please, provide your docker-compose.yml or at least the part of your otree service.

Comment: Added to the description of the question.